# should 'the' be repeated in front of two or more nouns?

Tags: articles, conjunction-reduction

If I list some similar things, should I place an article in front of each?

- Like: I want to be **a** pilot, or **a** teacher, or **an** artist, or **a** queen.
- Or: I have eaten **the** soup and **the** sandwich you made for me.

Comment: There is no strict rule here. It's a matter of style. In certain cases, pragmatics (ie precedent) will govern, but for the most part you are free to choose. Sometimes, repetition will seem superfluous and prolix, other times it can be used to great effect for emphasis or other rhetorical purposes, as with [*anaphora*](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/A/anaphora.htm).

Comment: Using the articles will give a more staccato effect, compartmentalising the categories and highlighting each in turn. Omitting all but the first will enhance the 'smooth flow' effect. Use which seems better to fit in any given case.

Comment: Could it be that 'I have eaten the soup and the sandwich you made for me' is said when the soup was cooked by somebody else, while 'I have eaten the soup and sandwich you made for me' refers to the situation when 'the' has a combining effect, attributing both things to one person?

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, Dan Bron wrote:

> There is no strict rule here. It's a matter of style. In certain cases, pragmatics (ie precedent) will govern, but for the most part you are free to choose. Sometimes, repetition will seem superfluous and prolix, other times it can be used to great effect for emphasis or other rhetorical purposes, as with [*anaphora*](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/A/anaphora.htm).

Answer (score 0):

In a comment, Edwin Ashworth wrote:

> Using the articles will give a more staccato effect, compartmentalising the categories and highlighting each in turn. Omitting all but the first will enhance the 'smooth flow' effect. Use which seems better to fit in any given case.